# Firebase UI - Auth - Use own layout

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

Is it possible to use my **own layout & buttons** for Firebase UI Auth on **Android**?

I basically want to implement the screen for choosing the identity provider (google, facebook, etc.) on my own and start the according flow from my click listener (e.g. using Butterknife):

```
@OnClick(R.id.login_btn_signInGoogle)  
public void signInGoogle(View view) {  
  // Start google sign in flow <--- This is what I do not know how to do it  
}

@OnClick(R.id.login_btn_signInFacebook)  
public void signInFacebook(View view) {  
  // Start facebook sign in flow <--- This is what I do not know how to do it 
}
```

I know firebase provides the possibility to customize the screen/theme, but it is not enough for my case.

In the worst case I will have to implement this using the standard firebase sdk methods.

Comment: You can use Firebase own UI with customization and flow from this link: https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/tree/master/auth

Answer (score 12):

For now all we can do is accept their layout on FirebaseUI as stated [here](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/issues/229). If we don't like we have to make our own sign in.
I really hope they provide some customization in the future.

In my app I have a separate logo and a separate background, so when you try to register with email, logo goes away, and the registration dialog doesn't interfere with the logo, like [here](https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/6012585/17325961/6ab298ce-587c-11e6-920c-3fee00695b22.png)
You can do it with .SetTheme and .SetLogo

```
 startActivityForResult(
                        AuthUI.getInstance()
                                .createSignInIntentBuilder()
                                .setTheme(R.style.FirebaseLoginTheme)
                                .setLogo(R.drawable.logo)
                                .setProviders(Arrays.asList(
                                        new AuthUI.IdpConfig.Builder(AuthUI.FACEBOOK_PROVIDER).build(),
                                        new AuthUI.IdpConfig.Builder(AuthUI.GOOGLE_PROVIDER).build(),
                                        new AuthUI.IdpConfig.Builder(AuthUI.EMAIL_PROVIDER).build()))
                                .setIsSmartLockEnabled(false)
                                .build(),
                        RC_SIGN_IN);
```

In styles.xml edit windowBackground for your FirebaseLoginTheme:

```
 <style name="FirebaseLoginTheme" parent="FirebaseUI">
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/login</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use your own layout & buttons for Firebase UI Auth on Android.

For Google and Facebook, You can use widgets provided in XML file like:

```
        <com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_google_login"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent"
            android:text="@string/btn_google_login"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

        <com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_facebook_login"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent"
            android:text="@string/btn_facebook_login"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>
```

Then you can use your "android:id" to perform action on onClick

Hope your question is answered.

**EDIT:**
For the google flow:

```
// Configure sign-in to request the user's ID, email address, and basic
        // profile. ID and basic profile are included in DEFAULT_SIGN_IN.
        GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestIdToken(Your web_client_id)
                .requestEmail()
                .build();

    btn_google_login = (SignInButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_google_login);

    btn_google_login.setSize(SignInButton.SIZE_STANDARD);
    btn_google_login.setScopes(gso.getScopeArray());

    btn_google_login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            //If you want everytime for user to ask the account to select.
            mGoogleApiClient.clearDefaultAccountAndReconnect();

            Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
            startActivityForResult(signInIntent,RC_SIGN_IN);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for the response, but I know how to use buttons, clicklisteners etc. in android, the question is more what to start in the onclick method to start the firebase flows? I updated the question for clarification

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: This is doing it using the standard firebase SDK right? Then I will have to implement the whole smartlock stuff etc on my own, correct?

Comment: Ok, then I will wait some days, possibly someone else can provide an answer where I can use the stuff provided by firebase ui but more customized. Thank you :)!

Comment: Custom theming is a feature in FirebaseUI, but custom layout of the so-called Nascar screen is not. If you want to do that, you can fork the FirebaseUI repo and make the changes in your fork.

Comment: Thank you, thats really unfortunate. Could you post this as an answer so that I could accept it?

Comment: This answer is for using with firebase auth, not firebase auth ui which handles everything in few lines of code